# InDesign Server CS5.5 "ReferenceError: User canceled this action/" on XML import

Tags: scripting, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

Recently when on mew InDesign documents when we try to import and xml file into the document I am getting this
**ReferenceError: User canceled this action.**
Does anyone have nay insight as to what this error actually is? XML is valid, Document checks out not sure what it is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

I lied, XML was in fact, not valid. Or to be more clear the XML was a valid document, but one of my attributes was not valid for InDesign to parse and it didn't like it. I had a invalid file path in the **href** attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this error is a modal dialog opening in InDesign, which in turn throws an error. I'm sure there are many ways this can happen.

In addition to the invalid file path you mentioned, this can also be caused if a linked reference changes. For example, if you link an image, close the InDesign document, and then modify the image. The solution is to open the InDesign file and you will see a modal box asking if you'd like to update the link. Once you can open the InDesign file cleanly, the error should go away.